# Vue2 expand value from method

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-composition-api

I hope this is really simple.
I have one component that looks like this:

```js
export default defineComponent({
  name: "Home",
  setup() {
    const { pages, loading, error } = useGetPages();

    return { pages, loading, error };
  },
});
```

Notice how it returns `{ pages, loading, error }`. What I would like to do, is return similar when using **onMounted**. Currently I have this:

```js
export default defineComponent({
  name: "Categories",
  setup(_, context) {
    const slug = ref(context.root.$route.params.slug);
    const result = ref({});

    const getCategory = (slug) => {
      console.log(slug);
      const { category, loading, error } = useGetCategory(slug);
      result.value = { category, loading, error }; // How can I return the expanded version of this?
    };

    onMounted(() => getCategory(slug.value));

    return { result };
  },
});
```

As you can see I am returning `{ result }` which means in my template I have to do `{{ result.category }}`, but what I actually want to do is `{{ category }}`.
I have tried returning `return result;` but that doesn't seem to work either.

Does anyone know what I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with a `reactive` object.

1. Change `result` into a [`reactive`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/basic-reactivity.html#reactive) object with initial values.
2. Use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to update `result` with the return value of `useGetCategory()`.
3. Return the spread of [`toRefs(result)`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#torefs).

```js
import { reactive, toRefs } from 'vue' // or from `@vue/composition-api` in Vue 2

export default {
  setup() {
    // 1️⃣
    const result = reactive({ category: null, loading: null, error: null });

    const getCategory = (slug) => {
      // 2️⃣
      Object.assign(result, useGetCategory(slug))
    };

    // 3️⃣
    return { ...toRefs(result) };
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-reactive-to-refs?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FCategories.vue)